# gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:amd64 missing

Tags: dpkg

I get this error and I am not able to remove install or reinstall anything:

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgnome-keyring-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'linux-headers-4.15.0-33': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Is there any solution for this? Please help.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop 18.04

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove problematic list-file for package:

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-4.15.0-33*
```

and reinstall it with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-4.15.0-33
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Two other packages may be reinstalled in the same way:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgnome-keyring-common gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:amd64
```